# Increment Id in Sharepoint

Tags: forms, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, auto-increment, infopath

I am trying to increment an Id in a Sharepoint list.
I have tried different settings in the online editor of Sharepoint under "Settings > List Settings > Edit Column > Calculated Value".

Another option I tried was to create a custom add form using InfoPath. 
In this custom form, I added a rule on my field contactId. The rule has two actions.

1. Create a Query to the Contacts table
2. Set the current Id equal to (the maximum idContacts + 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbGLt.jpg)

A thirth option I tried is to set a rule under Submit options. That way I thought when I submit my form it will check if idContacts is currently blank. It will Query the Contacts table, set the current idContacts as the (maximum idContacts + 1) and finally submit the data to my table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiAds.jpg)

Finally When I submit my form it gives a pop up message "Connecting to Server" then it redirects to my list but nothing is added to the list.

Does anyone know what my problem could be. Or does anyone know a proper way to do this. I already lookup up a lot of tutorials and other information but I can not find it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In theory you should be able to ignore the ID altogether, since SharePoint lists have an ID column out of the box, which is auto incremented.
So why do you want to increment it by hand?

Comment: I actually want to link my table to another table. Because it is a many to many relationship, I need an extra table to connect both tables and I cant use the same ID fields so I think I need custom ID field?

Comment: And you cannot use lookup fields for that?

Comment: I'll try that out and I'll let you know if it worked. Thanks for the help!